# Cordova media plugin deprecation plan?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, deprecation-warning

I was about to fork the cordova-plugin-media plugin to add a missing feature in the Android implementation, but noticed that on Apache's JIRA system there are a number of tasks related to a plan of deprecating this plugin.  Is there an alternative plugin that I should be working with instead?